# Files dragged and dropped show up in JavaScript but do not appear in request

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am trying to create a file upload form that will work through both drag and drop and generic upload buttons, but I am having trouble getting the drag and drops to upload.

At this point in the code, before sending the ajaxData object using jquery:

```
    var ajaxData = new FormData($form.get(0));

    if (droppedFiles) {
        $.each( droppedFiles, function(i, file) {
            ajaxData[i] = file;
        });
    }

    console.log(ajaxData)
```

The ajaxData dictionary shows all of the expected file names and file information for dragged and dropped files, but

However when I normally upload the files, through `<input type="file"/>` the ajaxData logs as a simple formData object that (seems to be) empty:

```
FormData {}__proto__: FormData
```

Now, when I examine the requests that are made, the ajaxData created by the drag and drop sends just the keys with no files,

```
csv1: 
csv2:
csv3:
```

whereas the generic upload sends the files as expected.

```
csv1: csv1.csv
...
```

Why don't the dragged files upload, even though I am seeing them in the JavaScript console when I don't see the generic uploads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) method of `FormData` to append properties to the `FordData` instance

```
ajaxData.append(i, file)
```

and [`.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) to get the value of the specific property of the `FormData` instance

```
ajaxData.get("csv1")
```